# What was 'The Incident'?

Tags: the-lost-room

The Lost Room revolves around the idea of a hotel room with very odd abilities to say the least. In this AMA the writer director suggests that there is a reason behind its qualities, although he doesn't say what that reason is in the post. [This is all he says](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/462ywz/i_am_christopher_leone_writerdirector_of/):

> I always end up figuring out the explanation whether or not I reveal it because it's part of making up the rules. In the beginning, NOT knowing the explanation is exciting when I'm creating a project, maybe for the same reason it's fun to watch. It's weird, it's intriguing, it makes me wonder what the purpose of it is. **But by the time I'm writing I have to have a working theory on how it all works to make sure the rules make sense and I'm not going to contradict myself later.** There is sometimes some fine-tuning as you go along, little realizations that may hone the explanation further, but it tends to deepen the explanation rather than change it.

So there is a reason, but I can't find out if he's actually said what that reason is anywhere. Anyone know?